# Fetch records from a table based on the condition in associated table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have two models `School` and `Expense` where school has many expenses, `Expense` has an attribute named `cost`

I'm trying to fetch only those schools with their expense cost greater than a certain value, let's say 1000, I tried this query

```
School.includes(:expenses).where("lower(schools.name) LIKE '%a%' and expenses.cost >= 1000").select('*').from('schools, expenses')
```

The problem with this query is its returning duplicate values if a school have multiple expenses with cost greater than 1000, what I want is only unique schools based on the condition.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
School.
joins(:expenses).
where("lower(schools.name) LIKE ?", "%a%"). # part of the code you shared
where("expenses.cost > ?", 1_000).
group("schools.id")
```

Comment: What if every school doesn't have expenses?

Comment: Since this is an inner join, those schools will be ignored. In our case, this is absolutely fine since we only want schools that have expenses greater than a certain value. In case you still want to include those schools (for whatever reason) before the query filters them, you can use an outer join like so: `School.join("LEFT OUTER JOIN expenses ON expenses.school_id = schools.id").where(conditions).group("schools.id")`

Comment: No problem. Little error in my comment above though. The method is `joins` and not `join`.